# Rate of convergence of covariance of functional

Tags: covariance, density-function, convergence

Consider $X_n$ and $Y_n$ to random variable that are bounded in probability.

I know that

$$cov(X_n, Y_n) = O(n^{-1})$$

and that

$$(X_n, Y_n) \rightarrow_d (E_1, E_2)$$

where $E_1$ and $E_2$ are two independent random variables. By continuous mapping theorem, we know that

$$(f(X_n), f(Y_n)) \rightarrow_d (f(E_1), f(E_2))$$

for every continuous function $f$.

I am wondering of based on this I can prove that

$$cov(f(X_n), f(Y_n)) = O(n^{-1})$$

?

For the moment I am able to prove that it goes to $0$ but I am not able to keep the rate.

Comment: Since you can prove the covariance of $f(X_n)$ and $f(Y_n)$ converges to zero, surely you must be using some unstated assumptions, because for general continuous functions $f$ that covariance doesn't even have to exist.  What are those additional assumptions?